# ASP.NET Webform Custom Settings

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I am having an issue when trying to create custom settings for a `gridview`.  I have a database set up as following:  User|Colors|TempID.  I want to be able to change the `gridview` colors based on a users name when it appears in the list.  So I have added the user Marcus to the database with a color of `#fef100`.  However when I try to pull in the settings I get the this: system.data.datarow instead of the username marcus.  Below is the code

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    string Settings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["userthemes"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con13 = new SqlConnection(Settings);
    SqlDataAdapter grid13 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [User],[Colors], [TempID] FROM userthemes.dbo.[Colors]", con13);
    DataTable tools13 = new DataTable();
    grid13.Fill(tools13);
    DataTable alltools13 = new DataTable();
    GridView10.DataSource = tools13;
    GridView10.DataBind();

    Label9.Text = tools13.Rows[0].ToString();

    foreach (DataRow row in tools13.Rows)
    {
        foreach (var item in row.ItemArray)
        {
            if (e.Row.Cells[1].Text == (tools13.Rows[0].ToString()))
            {
                e.Row.Cells[0].BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(tools13.Rows[1].ToString());
                e.Row.Cells[1].BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(tools13.Rows[1].ToString());
                e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(tools13.Rows[1].ToString());
                e.Row.Cells[3].BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(tools13.Rows[1].ToString());
                e.Row.Cells[4].BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(tools13.Rows[1].ToString());
                e.Row.Cells[5].BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(tools13.Rows[1].ToString());
                e.Row.Cells[6].BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(tools13.Rows[1].ToString());
                e.Row.Cells[7].BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(tools13.Rows[1].ToString());
                e.Row.Cells[8].BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(tools13.Rows[1].ToString());
                e.Row.Cells[9].BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(tools13.Rows[1].ToString());
                e.Row.Cells[8].ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(tools13.Rows[1].ToString());
                e.Row.Cells[9].ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(tools13.Rows[1].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be `tools13.Rows[0][0].ToString()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already looping all rows in `tools13`, you you can just use

```
e.Row.Cells[0].BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(row["Colors"].ToString());
```

However since it would be likely a user only has one color returned from the query, you can access the first row directly without the `foreach` loops.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    if (tools13.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        e.Row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(tools13.Rows[0]["Colors"].ToString());
        //or by column index instead of by name
        e.Row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(tools13.Rows[0][1].ToString());
    }
}
```

The `tools13.Rows.Count > 0` is needed to make sure you don't get an `index out of bounds` when a user has no Colors = empty DataTable.

Comment: Thanks a ton!  I was getting really frustrated with it not working.  Your solution worked like a charm.